# Posting a Partial View Model to the Same MVC Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

From the bare-bones MVC template, I have modified `Manage.cshtml` to include a partial, the `_AccountSettingsPartial`:

```
<section id="accountSettings">            
    @Html.Partial("_AccountSettingsPartial")
</section>
@if (ViewBag.HasLocalPassword)
{
    @Html.Partial("_ChangePasswordPartial")
}
```

`Manage.cshtml` does not use `@model` anywhere, and it is loaded in `AccountController.cs`, in `public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)`.

`_AccountSettingsPartial` uses `@model crapplication.Models.ManagePublicSettingsViewModel` and `_ChangePasswordPartial` uses `@model crapplication.Models.ManageUserViewModel`.

Originally, `AccountController.cs` had just a post method for `ManageUserViewModel`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManageUserViewModel model)
```

I have tried to overload it for the other partial:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(ManagePublicSettingsViewModel model)
```

But this does not work, and produces the following error on a post:

```
System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: The current request for action 'Manage' on controller type 'AccountController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] Manage(crapplication.Models.ManagePublicSettingsViewModel) on type crapplication.Controllers.AccountController
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] Manage(crapplication.Models.ManageUserViewModel) on type crapplication.Controllers.AccountController
```

How can I make my `_AccountSettingsPartial` page post back data from the user account management portal?

Comment: Looks like you have 2 methods with the same name and the compiler does not know which one you want to call. Rename one of the 2.

Comment: @Serv But then how do I associate what model I want to post to that view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have separate forms in your partials, in order to post to different actions. (Or you *could* change the action of a single form with JQuery, etc., but this will be easier.)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManagePublicSettings", "Account", FormMethod.Post))

...

@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageUser", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
```

You then need to uniquely name the actions.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ManagePublicSettings(ManagePublicSettingsViewModel model)

...

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ManageUser(ManageUserViewModel model)
```